# Unexpected this type in javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am receiving an unexpected `this` type in the following JavaScript:

```
var MyReservationsViewModel = (function () {
    function MyReservationsViewModel() {
        this.availableMeals = [
            { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
            { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
            { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
        ];
        this.self = this;
        this.self.seats = ko.observableArray([
            new SeatReservation("Steve", this.availableMeals[0]),
            new SeatReservation("Bert", this.availableMeals[0])
        ]);
    }
    MyReservationsViewModel.prototype.addSeat = function () {
        this.self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", this.availableMeals[0]));
    };
    MyReservationsViewModel.prototype.removeSeat = function (seat) {
        this.self.remove(seat);
    };
    return MyReservationsViewModel;
})();
;
var SeatReservation = (function () {
    function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
        var _this = this;
        this.name = name;
        this.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
        this.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
            var price = _this.meal().price;
            return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";
        });
    }
    return SeatReservation;
})();
var seat = new MyReservationsViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(seat);
```

The exception I receive is in:

```
MyReservationsViewModel.prototype.removeSeat = function (seat) {
            this.self.remove(seat);
        };
```

The problem is **this** is a type of SeatReservation

The HTML page for it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Passenger name</th>
                    <th>Meal</th>
                    <th>Surcharge</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
                <tr>
                    <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
                    <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>

        <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/MySeatReservation.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aren't you binding the inputs to each of the "seats" in a reservation?

Comment: `remove` is not working is this what you looking for ?

Comment: posted solution using prototype . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In knockout, the context of functions passed to the `click` binding is `$data` where the binding lives.  In your case, you're iterating over objects of type `SeatReservation` so that's your `$data` and therefore your function context.  If you want to bind to a function in a different context, you can just do:

```
data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat.bind($root)"
```

Another solution, and one that shows even better what is going on behind the scenes, is to make an alternate [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that would look like this:

```
data-bind="clickWithRootContext: $root.removeSeat"
```

You can pretty much copy the way the existing [click binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js#L11) works and change the context on the line I highlighted (`this` becomes `bindingContext.$root` I believe).

Actually, I like this idea so I'm going to go add it to my library of custom bindings (thank you :)).  Sorry to the other answer that seems correct, I was trying to provide a simpler explanation.

Comment: I tried to read by diagonal about this custom binding. And I simply scared. Better to use a global variable :)

Comment: @alerya, don't be scared!  :) So bindings in knockout are very simple to understand.  Take a look at how the `text` binding is implemented: http://goo.gl/8mN9Qk.  Basically, to make a binding one has to define an init function and an update function.  You put those functions in an object and assign that object to a property of `ko.bindingHandlers`, let's say `ko.bindingHandlers.alerya`.  Now, when you call `ko.applyBindings`, and knockout parses something like `data-bind="alerya: something"`, it runs your `init` function.  Then, every time `something` changes, it calls `update`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JSFiddle I made of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/9n00c5ht/) based on your description, and here's what I think is going on.

In the JSFiddle I posted, the "Reserve Reservation" button works but the "Remove" button does not.  To figure out why, try logging `this` in the two prototype functions:

```
MyReservationsViewModel.prototype.addSeat = function () {
    console.log(this);
    this.self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", this.availableMeals[0]));
};
MyReservationsViewModel.prototype.removeSeat = function (seat) {
    console.log(this);
    this.self.remove(seat);
};
```

addSeat() is called in the (binding) context of the overarching ViewModel object.  And `this`, in this context, refers to the MyReservationsViewModel - so it works.  removeSeat(), however, is called *within the binding context of `foreach:seats`*.  So `this` in this instance refers to a *SeatReservation*.  The function is trying to remove a `seat` from the MyReservationsViewModel, but because `this` refers to a SeatReservation instead, it doesn't work: a SeatReservation doesn't hold the seats observableArray - MyReservationsViewModel does.

I'm still interested in a solution to the problem; I hope this could lead you in the right direction.

Comment: frankly saying I am working with typescript. And this code is generated by it. Yes I can resolve it using global variable seat. But as for me this is extremely ugly solution !

Comment: Also another solution - don't use knockout.

Comment: @alerya knockout has its cons but its definitely something we should look for its pros

Comment: @alerya Just so you know, I wouldn't advocate using global variables to fix the problem - but you have to be very sensitive to scoping issues when working with Knockout.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't used prototype before but this will work for sure

```
var MyReservationsViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.availableMeals = [
            { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
            { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
            { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
        ];
        self.seats = ko.observableArray([
            new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
            new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
        ]);

    self.addSeat = function () {
           self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
    };

    self.removeSeat = function (data) {   
         self.seats.remove(data);
    }; 
};

var SeatReservation = function (name, initialMeal) {
        var self = this;
        self.name = name;
        self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
        self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
            var price = self.meal().price;
            return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";
        });
};

var seat = new MyReservationsViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(seat);
```

Working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/9n00c5ht/1/)

**With Prototype :**

**view :**

```
td><a href="#" data-bind="click: function (){$root.removeSeat($root,$data);}">Remove</a></td>
```

**View Model :**

```
MyReservationsViewModel.prototype.removeSeat = function (main,sub){
        console.log(main.seats);
        console.log(sub);
    main.seats.remove(sub);
    console.log(main);
    };
```

Working fiddle with prototype [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/864jh0x2/)

Comment: I am using typescript, and I cannot refuse this prototyping. Because it simulate OOP coding format.

Comment: gotcha working solution bro with prototype . please up vote and mark it is helpful

Comment: @supercool take a look at my answer, the anonymous function wrapper you use is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @Milimetric yes man  but `alerya` mentioned(necessary) it will stimulate oop coding format so in-turn it is mandate if i am not wrong (one way to do it next to custom approach) .